# How to make an extension configurable through extension manager (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am currently developing my own TYPO3 extension (in v 9.5.11) and I would like to make some settings of my extension customisable. When I go to Admin Tools-->Settings-->Extension Configuration-->Configure Extensions, I can already change those settings.

However in earlier versions of TYPO3 (e.g. v7) it was possible to also make an extension configurable through Admin Tools-->Extensions-->"clicking the settings wheel of the desired extension" (see picture).

[image: The Settings Wheel]

Where do I implement said function?

Comment: The extension configuration has been moved from the Extension Manager (TYPO3 7 and 8) to the place which you have already written about. Admin Tools-->Settings-->Extension Configuration-->Configure Extensions

Comment: Oh okay. So there is no way to get that nice looking settings wheel into your extension manager? Because there is still the exact same amount of room for configuring, downloading, deleting etc.

Comment: The configuration wheel in the Extension Manager has gone with TYPO3 9.5. There is only the way to write your own TYPO3 extension to bring it back again.

Answer (score 5):

You simply define your desired settings in the file `ext_conf_template.txt` which needs to be stored in the root level of your extension.

The [official TYPO3 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html) contains detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Like Michael said, you need to put all settings into the `ext_conf_template.txt`

Here is an example of my extension "slug" wich you can also find on [Github](https://github.com/koehlersimon/slug) or in the [TYPO3 repository](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/slug/). It contains some special fields and even translations.

```
# Settings
###########################

# cat=defaults; type=options[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,150,200,300,400,500]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:default.maxentries
defaultMaxEntries = 20

# cat=defaults; type=options[crdate,tstamp,title,slug,sys_language_uid,is_siteroot,doktype]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:default.orderby
defaultOrderBy = crdate

# cat=defaults; type=options[DESC,ASC]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:default.order
defaultOrder = DESC

# cat=defaults; type=boolean; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:default.recordInfoEnabled
recordInfoEnabled = 1


# cat=tree; type=boolean; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:tree.enabled
treeEnabled = 1

# cat=tree; type=options[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:tree.depth
treeDefaultDepth = 3

# cat=tree; type=string; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:tree.root
treeDefaultRoot =


# cat=custom records; type=boolean; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:record.enabled
recordEnabled = 0

# cat=custom records; type=options[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,150,200,300,400,500]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:record.maxentries
recordMaxEntries = 10

# cat=custom records; type=options[crdate,title,path_segment,sys_language_uid]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:record.orderby
recordOrderBy = crdate

# cat=custom records; type=options[DESC,ASC]; label=LLL:EXT:slug/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:record.order
recordOrder = DESC
```

And here is how I use the settigs in any Controller I want:

```
<?php    
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ExtensionConfiguration;

class ExtensionController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

       public function __construct() {
            $this->backendConfiguration = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ExtensionConfiguration::class)->get('slug');
       }

       public function myRandomFunction(){
           $variable = $this->backendConfiguration['recordMaxEntries'];
       }

}
```

This is how it looks:
[image]